# git equivalent of 'hg rename -A'

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a git equivalent of `hg rename -A` in Mercurial, which renames a file in the version control repository "after the fact", in case I or an application I run decides to rename a file?

Comment: You could use `mv` to rename it back to the original name, then `git mv` to rename it to the new name again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't actually record renames: instead, it synthesizes them later, when comparing two trees (as for `git show` or `git log -p`, or even `git status`).  So it's not *necessary* to use `git mv` to create-and-record a rename operation.

As [Keith Thompson noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127000/git-equivalent-of-hg-rename-a#comment50266670_31127000), you can use the two-step method of putting the name back temporarily, then using `git mv` to un-undo (or re-do) the rename along with the steps needed to get git to see it.  But you can also `git rm --cached` the old name and `git add` the new name to update the index.  As long as the file contents are unchanged (or sufficiently similar), git will subsequently show the file as moved.